# Application does DNS outside of its Network Namespace?

Tags: dns, networkmanager, dnsmasq, network-namespaces

I am using unshare to create a network namespace:

```
unshare -rn bash
```

I already have the a working setup with veth-interfaces  as described in this guide:

https://josephmuia.ca/2018-05-16-net-namespaces-veth-nat/

or in this script: https://gist.github.com/dpino/6c0dca1742093346461e11aa8f608a99

for internet connectivity. I also disabled IPv6 for the veth-devices. I use nftables to send all outgoing DNS traffic to my dns-proxy.

```
/usr/sbin/nft add table nat
/usr/sbin/nft add chain nat output "{ type nat hook output priority filter; policy accept;}"
/usr/sbin/nft add rule nat output udp dport 53 dnat 10.200.1.1:53
```

I tried `dig example.com` and its being send to my dns-proxy as I wanted and ping does work fine to.

Next I create a User and PID Namespace

```
unshare -pf --mount-proc --map-user=1000 --map-group=1000
```

inside of the Network Namespace, I also confirmed that with `ip a` that I am still in the Network Namespace and `dig example.com` comes back the same as before. Now when I start a application like vs code, I noticed that the dns-traffic shows up on the host eth-device but not on the veth-device. And that its not forward to my dns-proxy. As to why that's happening is unclear to me, because its only the DNS-related traffic that is not going through the veth-devices. I also tried to change the `/etc/resolv.conf` inside the Network Namespace but that didn't change anything and I would like to mention that resolv.conf is being generated by NetworkManager.

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with it, but if you have systemd-resolved running, apparently some programs can issue DNS requests to it via a "local API" (in which case the `nameserver`s in `/etc/resolv.conf` will not be relevant): https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html

Comment: Perhaps try using `strace` on your application within the network namespace and see whether the domain in question appears in the output.